# Doctrine findBy* methods and fetch array

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

What is the cleanest way of using the Doctrine findBy methods but getting an array returned and not objects.

```
Doctrine::getTable('Table')->findOneById(x);
```

That works but returns a doctrine object.

I'd still like to be able to use the find methods but I know I can't add

```
->fetchArray()
```

on the end.

Anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use [toArray](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/en/working-with-models%3aarrays-and-objects%3ato-array)

```
Doctrine::getTable('Table')->findOneById(x)->toArray();
```

Comment: If you do this, you will first fetch an object and then convert it to an array, which is not efficient memory-wise.

Answer (score 20):

You can specify the hydration mode when using magic finders, like so:

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('Table')->findOneById($x, Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 3):

Haim Evgi and DuoSRX's answers are correct, but there's a slightly different version for both that I prefer when using Symfony:

Let's say your model name is Person, you would use:

`PersonTable::getInstance()->findOneById(x)->toArray();`

or

`PersonTable::getInstance()->findOneById($x, Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);`

Comment: So what is the difference ?

Comment: @NBPalomino: The first one retrieves the full Object and converts it to an Array, the second one retrieves it directly as an Array (which uses less memory and is faster). I'd advice to use Array Hydration whenever you need to retrieve information without updating the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
$adCampaign = $em->createQuery('select c from \Model\Campaign c where c.client = ?1')
->setParameter(1, $clientId)
->getArrayResult();
```

where em is the entityManager - you get the result as array with getArrayResult

Comment: I think you'll find your answer relates to Symfony 2.x (Doctrine 2) which supports namespaces and the entity manager service, whereas the original question is tagged Symfony 1